# The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType

Tags: xml

I have the below XSD & when I am trying to generate XML out of it I am getting the above error : ***Error!!! The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType.*** *Need your help suggestions in resolving the issue*.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="InvoiceData" type="InvoiceData">
<xs:complexType name="InvoiceData">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="HeaderFields" type="HeaderFields">
<xs:complexType name="HeaderFields">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="CompanyId" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="ImageID" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="Incident" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="FacilityID" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define the type of your element inline you can't name it so remove the `type="InvoiceData"` attribute (and then the `name="InvoiceData"` attribute as well).

If you want to use those attributes then you need to separate element and type definition e.g. `<xsl:element name="InvoiceData" type="InvoiceData"/>` and `<xsl:complexType name="InvoiceData">...</xsl:complexType>`.

The complete schema would be either

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="InvoiceData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="HeaderFields">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="CompanyId" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ImageID" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Incident" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="FacilityID" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

or

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="InvoiceData" type="InvoiceData"/>

  <xs:complexType name="InvoiceData">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="HeaderFields" type="HeaderFields"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="HeaderFields">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="CompanyId" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="ImageID" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Incident" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="FacilityID" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Martin, Thanks for your reply but can you please post the entire the xml with your fixes ? Also when I have raw xml so how can i convert that into the valid xsd ? because it will not add type & all that extra parameters is there any utility or online xsd generate which can execute it proper.

Comment: @RahulJain, I added two samples.

Comment: Martin, is there any online utility where I can generate XSD ? based upon your 2nd example ?

Comment: @RahulJain, I don't know, I am sure there are XML IDEs like Stylus Studio or oXygen that allow schema generation and these days I think that general programming IDEs like Visual Studio also have XML editing and validation support, I don't know which online tools there are and which features they have, you will need to search the web and experiment which the ones you find.

Comment: Martin, You have mentioned 2 ways to get the output so what is the name of the 1st example & 2nd example. I was able to generate the 1st example from the visual studio but 2nd one was not generated automatically. So what should I do to generate the 2nd example ?

Comment: The first sample uses inline, anonymous types, the second sample named types. That is as far as I understand the terminology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87886/discussion-between-rahul-jain-and-martin-honnen).